# Android set image of one imagebutton from image of another button

Tags: android

I have two imagebuttons, now I want to set the image of one button from the image of another button.So how can I successfully do that? I need to get the image of imageButton1 first, and set this image to imageButton2.

```
ImageButton imageButton1=(ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.beans);
ImageButton imageButton2=(ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 
***imageButton1.getDrawable()*** or ***imageButton1.getBackground()*** to get image of ImageButton.

Comment: imageButton1.getDrawable() will return Drawable instead of int

Comment: so, what's the problem?

Comment: I tried imageButton2.setImageDrawable(imageButton1.getDrawable()) but the appication crashes. I think it should use  imageButton2.setImageResource but can't find the right parameters

Comment: use setBackgroundDrawable(drawable) to set image or Convert drawable to bitmap and use setImagebitmap(bmp)

Comment: @xiang Can you please share crash log.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.mobileapp.fresh.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:147)

Comment: 147 is imageButton2.setImageDrawable(imageButton1.getDrawable());

Comment: @xiang Your imageButton2 or imageButton1 is surely null, cross check both buttons id in layout.

Answer (score 0):

Use setTag() and getTag() to associate and retrieve custom data for your ImageButton